# Can exe file Install pfx file in Windows Certificate Store With Python

Tags: python, windows, certificate, digital-signature, signtool

I use ***Self Code sign Certificate*** and sign exe file using Windows SDK ***signtool.exe*** through PowerShell.

Exe file successfully signed. But for other systems This Sign Doesn't work. Because other system Doesn't have my
Code Sign Certificate in form of pfx file.

So what I do For that:

I have two options : Through the help of python script which includes an exe file. that performs a pfx file install in Windows certificate Store at time of exe file run as administrator and i get Publisher Name.
But how this thing is possible !!

Or Suggest Other ways to do this.

**Simply I ask Self Sign Code Certificate run in all system.**

Thank you.

Comment: So do you just want a solution that installs your certificate silently before running the rest of your program?

Comment: Yes, I want to only run my exe freely on windows.

Comment: That's a bit of chicken and an egg problem. Won't that exe that install the certificate have to be signed by your untrusted certificate too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certificates are validated through trust certificate chain. The trust chain of the leading code signing providers are already present as a part of OS. Thus they don't require to distribute their certificates.

If at all, you want to use your own certificate (irrespective of which OS will trust it), you may create your own private CA (google for it) and then use your private CA certificate to sign your code signing certificate.  You may distribute certificate of your private CA (certificate don't have private keys... contains only public keys...).

It's not good idea to distribute your pfx since it also contains private key and anybody can use the certificate which is again stealing your identity...

BTW, Certifying Authorities issuing code signing certificates, has some cost verifying your identity and that is the reason they are charging the amount (for some countries it becomes large amount though...!!)

Answer (score 1):

I have found another way to do it. I created the setup of the executable file using Inno Setup Creator and after installation on the system it stopped displaying blue screen that this is an unrecognized program.

Comment: I have tested Inno setup and created an exe file with a logo but I am not sure how to attach the self-code certificate of legal certificate and also the version of windows like windows7,8,10 and also the bit Operating system 32/64 bit. So finally still I didn't get the solution.

Comment: I have done all of that by using signtool, give me your email I will share you steps to handle it

Comment: You can't do anything for windows versions , the operating system doesn't needs to be decided just build the exe with 32 bit architecture, it will automatically run on 64-bit os.

Comment: Thank you @graj499. my email_address/GitHub is rajmehta28599v@gmail.com I have a windows10 64bit system. but I want to build software windows XP 32bit system. that thing I know if I build windows7 32bit then this exe file working well all above version like windows 7,8,10,.. and 32/64 system. Thanks again.